# Put a photo in the div that takes the rest of its father

Tags: html, css

I want something like this:

```
**************************************************************************
*                                                              *   div2  *
*                                                              *         *
*                                                              ***********
*                                                              *   div3  *
*                             div1                             * (image) *
*                                                              *         *
*                                                              *         *
*                                                              *         *
*                                                              *         *
*                                                              *         *
**************************************************************************
```

The `div1` on the left has content and its height is adjusted with its content height. The `div2` contains some text, and `div3` only has one image. I want the total height of `div2` and `div3` equal to the height of `div1` but when I put the photo in it, it leaves the frame.
In the title of the question I have said that `div3` takes the remainder of its father's height but It is not important that `div3` is placed immediately after `div2` (like the below code) or their height ratio is 20 to 80.

```css
.container {
   width: 100%
 }

 .left-side {
   width: 80%;
   background-color: red;
   float: left;
 }

 .right-side {
   text-align: center;
   width: 20%;
   background-color: blue;
   float: right;
 }

 .top {
   background-color: green;
 }

 .bottom img {
   height: auto;
   width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class="left-side">
    <p>Line 1</p>
    <p>Line 2</p>
    <p>Line 3</p>
    <p>Line 4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right-side">
    <div class="top">
      TOP
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      <img  src='https://www.kindpng.com/picc/m/73-736150_ios-arrow-thin-down-small-down-arrow-symbol.png'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please check this post https://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/ 
this might helpful for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it with `flex` and removed all `float`

```css
.container {
   display:flex;
   
 }

 .left-side {
   width: 80%;
   background-color: red;
 }

 .right-side {
    display:flex;
   flex-direction:column;
   text-align: center;
   width: 20%;
   background-color: blue;
 }

 .top {
   background-color: green;
 }

 .bottom img {
   height: auto;
   width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class="left-side">
    <p>Line 1</p>
    <p>Line 2</p>
    <p>Line 3</p>
    <p>Line 4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right-side">
    <div class="top">
      TOP
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      <img  src='https://www.kindpng.com/picc/m/73-736150_ios-arrow-thin-down-small-down-arrow-symbol.png'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `grid` and simplify the html

```css
img {
  display:block;
  }
  
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 80% 20%;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
 }

 .left-side {
   background-color: red;
   grid-row: span 2;
 }

 .top {
   background-color: green;
 }

 .bottom img {
   width:100%;
 }
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class="left-side">
    <p>Line 1</p>
    <p>Line 2</p>
    <p>Line 3</p>
    <p>Line 4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="top">
    TOP
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <img src='https://www.kindpng.com/picc/m/73-736150_ios-arrow-thin-down-small-down-arrow-symbol.png'>
  </div>
</div>
```

And if you want to put an image in div1 you can add the role:

```css
    .left-side img {
      width:100%;
    }
```

Comment: In my work the left `div` must adjust the height of all `.container` (`.container` height is equal to height of `.left-side`), but in your code right side does this. If you delete two of the `p` tags, you will see the result.

Comment: div1 (.left-side) defines the overall height of the container (try to add content), but the minimun height of .container is influenced by the ratio of the image you put in div3. What do you want to happen to your div3 image when div 1 has only two <p>?